# How to make two elements to be under each other in a list of inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my program, I want to have a list of my inputs to be under each other. However, if the input of the foods field is shorter/longer (let's say it's apple) than the one above it (cabbage), the inputs of datefield shift themselves.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This program is for a school project and I am stuck with this problem since 2 weeks.

```js
function addFoodsAndDate(event) {
  foodsdate.innerHTML += `
                <li class="mdl-list__item">
                  <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                      ${foodsfield.value}
                  </span>
                  <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                      ${datefield.value}
                  </span>
                </li>
                    `;

  foodsfield.value += ``;
  datefield.value += ``;

  return false;
}
```

```css
.demo-list-item {
  width: 320px;
}

.page-content {
  padding: 20px 100px;
  float: left
}

body {
  background: #3d3d3d
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>



<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Kühlflex Web-App</span>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content">
      <!-- Your content goes here -->

      <form onsubmit="return addFoodsAndDate()">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="foodsfield">
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="foodsfield">Deine Lebensmittel...</label>
        </div>

        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9+.]*(\.[0-9+.]+)?" id="datefield">
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="datefields">Datum...</label>
          <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Datum eingeben!</span>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
                              Hinzufügen
                            </button>
      </form>


      <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list" id="foodsdate">

      </ul>

    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

I already tried the `float: left` method but I'm unsure if I used it correctly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This can be solved in many ways. Try reading up on `flex` with `justify-content` or `flex `with `flex-grow` or even `margin-left` / `margin-right` with `auto` property.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried to use them but I don't undestand how I can do it that only the elements in the list are being moved and not the whole content of the page. Where do you put it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with `flex`. You add `display: flex;` to the `<li>` element and the direct children are placed the "flex way". With `justify: content;` the children are placed an equal distance apart from each other, as far as the parent container allows. The parent I've set to `320px` so the first child is placed at the beginning and the last is "pushed" to the end. If there were more than two children, they would be placed with equal distance to each other and span all `320px` (I've added an example of that).

There are many more ways of spacing items, but this is an easy and popular (and more modern?) way of doing it:

```css
.mdl-list {
  width: 320px;
}

.mdl-list__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list" id="foodsdate">
  <li class="mdl-list__item">
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
       Apple
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
       12.12.22
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="mdl-list__item">
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
       Cabbage
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
       12.12.22
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="mdl-list__item">
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
       Many
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
       items
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
       with
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
       equal
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
       space
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. Could you do it with the inputs?

Comment: I'm not following. You want the input fields placed side by side, or? For that you could use flex on the form element.

Comment: No, I want the words that you write into the input fields being evenly spaced. So that you write them in the input fields and the list of them is evenly spaced.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format tabular / two-dimensional data, use a `<table>`.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
th,
td {
  width: 40vw;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Deine Lebensmittel</th>
    <th>Datum</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="lebensmittel">Apple</td>
      <td class="datum">2022-12-12</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="lebensmittel">Cabbage</td>
      <td class="datum">2022-12-12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
</table>
```

Comment: It won't work, could you do it with the inputs. So that you can write multiple things and then they are below eachother.